# Как перенастроить раздел "Оформление заказа" на Wordpress | Woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно переместить радиокнопку "Доставка по другому адресу?" в самый верхний уровень полей вводы, как показано на картинке:
[image: Доставка по другому адресу]

[image: Сюда нужно переместить]

Также как переименовать "Доставка по другому адресу?" в другой текст? я лазил в файликах woocommerce и ничего похожего на ту надпись не нашел.

Пробовал различные плагины, но ни один из них не имеет нужного мне функционала.

Comment: Частично решил проблему с помощью плагина "Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce", скрыв основные поля, тем самым переместив радиокнопку "Доставка по другому адресу?" в самый верх, остальные поля сделал в дополнительном разделе. Но вопрос по переименованию "Доставка по другому адресу?" все еще остается.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения данной задачи понадобилось 2 плагина:
1) Checkout Field Editor for WooCommerce
2) Loco Translate

С помощью первого плагина я расположил формы полей заполнения как мне нужно, со вторым плагином я нашел фразу "Доставка по другому адресу?" и переименовал по своим требованиям.